# sqlite row data increment in laravel

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel

Using Laravel and sqlite I'm trying to increment a value that represents how many comments are on the next page. The problem I'm having is the value that needs to be incremented is in a button as the "label" so I can't pull the value from it using `Input::get('commentCounter')`.

Here are the functions that are called when I delete and post a comment:

```
function commentcountdelete($id){
    $commentcounter = Input::get('commentcounter');
    $sql = "Update status Set commentCount = ?-1 WHERE id = ?";
    $results = DB::update ($sql, array($commentcounter,$id));
    return $results;
}

function commentcountIncrement($id){
    $commentcounter = Input::get('commentcounter');
    $sql = "Update status Set commentCount = ?+1 WHERE id = ?";
    $results = DB::update ($sql, array($commentcounter,$id));
    return $results;
}
```

Here's where the value needs to be extracted from:

```
<a href ="{{{ url("comments_post/$post->Id") }}}"><button id="commentBTN" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Comments: {{{$post->commentCount}}}</button></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in routes.php

```
Route::post('comments_post/{commentcounter}', '{your Controller}@{your view}');
```

It will send id to your controller and you will be able to use that

Answer (score 1):

1. Please Make sure in route.php file

> Route::get('comments_post/{commentcounter}', 'yourController@commentcountIncrement');

2. in the link we should use action instead of url
   it will be like

> href ="{!!
>   action("yourController@commentcountIncrement",["commentcounter"=>$post->Id
>   ] ) !!}"